Jquery Text Function Only Works Twice
I'm trying to run this script many times but it only works twice.
What it's supposed to do is ..Type a city name in the text box and then submit it and a function occurs. but it only works twice


$("#b").click(function() {
  var password = "toronto";
  if ($("#pass").val() == password) {
    $(".tim1").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    return true;
  }

});
$("#b").click(function() {
  var password = "ottawa";
  if ($("#pass").val() == password) {
    $(".tim2").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    return true;
  }

});
body {
  background-color: #6A6A6A;
}

.tim1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.tim2 {
  background-color: #525119;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="pass"> <input type="button" id="b" value="Guess">
<div class="tim1"></div>
<div class="tim2"></div>




What specifically do you mean by "it only works twice"?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

What is it that you a actually trying to achieve? Do you want to hide the box at any point or is it a guessing game where you need to guess a word and if it is a match then show the element?

Looks like you need to set display prop back to 'none' somewhere. For example, when you are "showing" tim1, you should "hide" tim2 and vice versa.

The code "works", but you've styled two elements to occupy the exact same space at the same time.  You probably want to hide them when performing the operation again.
You can also simplify the operation.  There's no need to attach multiple click handlers here.  All you need is a click handler which:

Hides the elements
Checks the input against known good values
Conditionally shows the relevant element

For example:


$("#b").click(function() {
  // initially hide the elements
  $(".tim1, .tim2").hide();

  // read the user input
  const password = $("#pass").val();

  // conditionally show the relevant element
  if (password === "toronto") {
    $(".tim1").show();
  } else if (password === "ottawa") {
    $(".tim2").show();
  }
});
body {
  background-color: #6A6A6A;
}

.tim1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.tim2 {
  background-color: #525119;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="pass"> <input type="button" id="b" value="Guess">
<div class="tim1"></div>
<div class="tim2"></div>




You've assigned two click handlers to #b, this maybe a source of your frustrations. You can combine them with a simple else-if:
$("#b").click(function () {
    var password = $("#pass").val();
    if (password == "toronto") {
        $(".tim1").css({ "display": "block" });
    } else if (password == "ottawa") {
        $(".tim2").css({ "display": "block" });
    }
});


not a case for else if that will perform slowly. Either use toggle() or switch statements

ok i tried the else if way but it still only runs each once .. like if i type ottawa then toronto then ottawa again it doesnt work..
$("#b").click(function () {
var password = $("#pass").val();
if (password == "toronto") {
$(".tim1").css({ "display": "block" });
} else if (password == "ottawa") {
$(".tim2").css({ "display": "block" });
} else if (password == "montreal") {
$(".tim3").css({ "display": "block" });
}
});

what do you mean it doesn't work? If you run ottawa, is toronto supposed to be hidden again?

@Timbukto: Sure it does.  But you've styled two elements to occupy the exact same space at the same time.  Did you forget to hide the elements when you no longer want to see them?

The if block needs to hide tim2, and the else if block needs to hide tim1

Or do it like the other answer and hide both of them first.
